# Inverted "repeat" function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, standard-library

There is a Kotlin Standard Library `repeat()` function that allows for executing a given function specified number of times and retrieving the index of a current repetition. For example:

```kotlin
repeat(3) {
    println(it)
}
```

Is there a function that will do the same in reverse order? In a way, the indices descend?

Comment: `(1..3).forEach { }` shoud do.

Comment: @al3c What I need is indices in reverse order. In this case `(3..1).forEachIndexed { }` would do, however, I'm asking about the `repeat()` function specifically.

Comment: `println(2-it)`

Comment: Why do you want a specifc function to have a specfic behvior? `repeat` doesn't do that: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html . For the reverse order `(3 down to 1).forEach {}` is the most appropriate. `(3..1)` returns an empty collection afaik

Comment: @al3c Sure, I meant `(3 down to 1)` obviously! Well, `repeat()` was created to replace `forEach()` in cases like that. That's why I'm asking for a solution that will suit my needs.

Comment: There's no standard library function for this.

Comment: Why do you need it to be `repeat`?

Comment: @al3c And "why does anyone do anything"? Self development, curiosity, getting to know the tool. Sorry, I didn't think the reason was important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no version of the stdlib [`repeat()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html) function that counts down.

That's probably because it's so easy to use other structures such as [`forEach()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html).  (And if you care enough about the passed value to want a particular ordering, then that would probably be a good idea as it'd make it explicit.)

But if you really don't want to use that directly, it's dead easy to write your own:

```
inline fun repeatReverse(times: Int, action: (Int) -> Unit)
    = (times downTo 1).forEach(action)
```